# Error: /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1 when try to archive xamarin.ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, xamarin.ios, applet

i have xamarin forms project work fine in debug when try to archive xamarin ios to generate ipa with valid certificate.

i tried build & clean & rebuild & restart visual studio and restart mac device more time with no solution also tried to delete certificate inside keychain and download certificate again but not resolved each time try to build project give me these two errors:

- Error: /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1
  *Error: Failed to codesign 'bin/iPhone/Release/CustomerApp.iOS.app': Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution: CerificateName"

any one can help
thanks.

Comment: Hi, could you share the screenshot of **Keychain Access** belows **System**? I will check that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT thanks for your response i fixed the problem 
and the problem reason is i deleted system certificates from Keychain Access and solution is  restored deleted certificate and every things work fine now thanks again for your response

Comment: Great, glad you have solved that! Remember to update the solution in answer, and others who have the same problems will know that.

Comment: @ahmedgaberI am facing the same problem now. How did you restore the missing system certificates?